# What books other than his sahih imam Muslim has written?

Tags: history, islamic-scholar, books

What books other than his sahih [imam Muslim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muslim_ibn_al-Hajjaj) has written and which of those has reached us (Examples should be sufficient if exist)?

When we look at the relief of his teacher imam [al-Bukhari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_al-Bukhari) we find that except with his so called sahih, we still have access to his [al-Adab al-Mufrad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Adab_al-Mufrad) and his tarikh books (al-Kabir, al-Awsat, as-Saghir), his ad_Do'afa' al-Kabir and as-Sagir and many other papers and books have reached us while many are lost like his tafsir al-Kabir, his 'ilal, his al-Musnad al-Kabir,his al-Mabsoot etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if there is a comprehensive list documented, or even if the full manuscript of any of the books below is available:

- [Al-Kuna wa al-Asmā'](https://archive.org/details/waq2976) is organized alphabetically, with each letter having its own chapter (very similar to Al-Bukhari's book with a similar title, but with Imam Muslim's views), which is used in [biographical evaluations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biographical_evaluation) (Arabic: علم الرجال) in terms of who was the teacher of whom, and so on.
- [Al-Munfaridāt wa al-Wihdān](https://archive.org/details/waq23116) is as its title implies, a compilation of hadiths that come through a single narrator, and an analysis of [biographical evaluations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biographical_evaluation) (Arabic: علم الرجال) quite similar to *Al-Kuna wa al-Asmā'*.
- [At-Tamyeez](https://archive.org/details/waq90443) is about the hadiths that [Muslim ibn al-Hajjaj](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muslim_ibn_al-Hajjaj) considered not authentic due to (hidden detrimental flaw (*'illah*, Arabic: عله), followed the discerning (*tamyeez*, Arabic: تمييز) of why there is a flaw (or more), followed by the authentic narrations negating the flawed ones, all classified in a similar manner to a *musannaf*.